# Broken table structure

Tags: css, html-table, viewport

I'm trying to fix a table structure in the mobile view port (a messy code that isn't mine, but I need to fix it *without* adding additional classes).

Below I've tried to illustrate the scenario, and below that you can see the code. Hope this is enough otherwise I'll put in additional code.

**This is how it looks without additional css in the viewport:**

```
 _________________
|    |            |
| av |  text      |
|____|____________|
|    |            |
| av |  username  |
|____|____________|
```

**This is how it looks with my css:**

```
 ______
|      |          
| text |          
|______|__________
|_av|  |          |
       |          |
       | username |
       |__________|
```

**This is how I want it to look:**

```
 _________________
|                 |
|      text       |
|_________________|
|    |            |
| av |  username  |
|____|____________|
```

av = avatar

**html:**

```
  <div class="row-fluid post-comment">      
    <div class="span6 offset3 margin-small">
        <table class="table table-condensed no-table-border">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="avatar">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40" class="img-circle">                            
                    </td>
                    <td class="text">
                        <p>text...</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="user-card">
                    <td rowspan="2" class="avatar">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" class="img-circle">                            
                    </td>
                    <td rowspan="2" class="username">
                        // content
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**css:**

```
.post-comment .span6 td.avatar {
    display: none;
}

.post-comment .span6 .user-card td.avatar {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: You can't add classes, but can you edit the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no additional classes are allowed, Im guessing editing the HTML isn't allowed either.

I found a real dirty way to make it work:

```
.post-comment .span6 td.avatar {
    display: none;
}
.post-comment .span6 table {
    width: 120px;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.post-comment .span6 table td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: lightblue;
}
.post-comment .span6 td.text {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 120px;
}

.post-comment .span6 .user-card td.avatar,
.post-comment .span6 .user-card td.username{
    display: table-cell;
    padding-top: 55px;
}
```

The `.text` table-cell is displayed as a absolute block, above the other cells. To make the cells appear under the `.text` a padding-top is added.

Like I said, a dirty way, but [**it works**](http://jsfiddle.net/EN9tX/).

Answer (score 0):

In second TR, every TD has rowspan="2". Remove that. Your first TR has only 2 TD. It should work as expected then.